# Why can't I access variables when I subclass a customised UIViewController?

Tags: objective-c, ios, properties, uitableview, subclassing

I am new to iOS dev and apologies if the answer is obvious...but it isn't to me.
I have an APP with a Navigation controller at its root.
I have many very similar looking areas of the app to be created.
These are each to be UItableviewcontroller which has had a fair bit of customising done to allow buttons and other controls beside the tableview which has been reduced in size to allow for controls beside and below it.
The buttons, text, background etc etc and the data that gets loaded must all be individual to the particular are of the APP.
I created a UItableviewcontroller subclass by simply adding a new file subclass in Xcode.
I created my interface in the xib...created all the methods to drive what I need to in it.
Looks great...all seems fine. If I use it alone...works well.

Problem: I can't figure out how to subclass my custom sub-classed UITVController!
None of its properties are available from inside the new sub-class.
I clearly don't understand how things work here.

I have tried adding a new file > UIViewcontroller sub-class and changing the superclass to my custom superclass...to no avail. No properties accessible.

I have dug and dug and become more confused than anything else.
Is someone kind enough to help me get it right. Frustration is building.
Thanks
Keispe

EDIT:
Whoa found the problem. I have had Xcode open for many many days with several projects open.
It had totally weirded out!
In fact jrturton and eugene...I did know what I was doing (I thought I was going crazy...done this before in my app and suddenly no worky) Xcode had totally lost it's brains!

Anyone seen Xcode do that before??? using 4.1

Bloody hell that wasted a heap of valuable time including yours.
Thanks fellas

Comment: Please include the .h files of your subclass and your sub-sub class as they currently stand.

Comment: OK I will edit and include a very cut down example. The actual app controller files are large with many many vars etc.
Even with the example I will post I can't get it to work. 
Thanks jrturton

Comment: I've had it do funny stuff which is fixed on a restart, yes. Most annoying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you subclass anything, you can access your parent's class properties by addressing self via dot syntax

```
@interface BaseClass : NSObject {
 @public
  NSString *baseclassString;
}

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *name;

@end
```

.h

```
@interface HigherClass : BaseClass

@end
```

.m

```
@implementation HigherClass

- (id)init {
  self = [super init];
  self.name = @"Hola";
  self->baseclassString = @"Hola";
  return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
  NSLog(@"name: %@", self.name);
}
@end
```

This all isn't 100% memory clean but you've gotta get a hang of what is happening here and adjust it properly to your application.

Comment: And so if I wanted to use it without local dot notation I could redeclare and assign in the subclass?

Comment: You could do so, but that's not what you need to. Try addressing 'self->localVariable', the -> sign accesses your local variables that are declared in the header file instead of properties. Just make sure to set your local variables in the superclass as @public.

Comment: OK...thanks. Aren't all vars really public anyway or is that @public to ensure the compiler behaves itself?

Comment: It for the compiler as you've said. Though I don't really know about the new compiler and ARC, that might generate an error message.

Comment: Right...not certain I understand what you mean by "Try addressing 'self->localVariable'"  an example would be nice...
in baseclass.h:

 NSString *baseclassString: